# Outlook export to file - missing mailbox accounts, only "Outlook Data File" is available

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, export

I should perform an operation on different customers outlook clients: exporting the destination email ("To") list of the last year. Actually the recipient mailbox of all the sent email of the year.

I'm not experienced with Outlook since I'm a linux user and I use thunderbird email client on my desktop. But I'm trying to understand how could achieve that using outlook 14.0.7 - Office 2010.

I understood that to perform this operation I should click on

> File > Open > Import > Export to a file > Comma Separated Values

and finally I should **select the mailbox from where** I want to export this data.

I'm stuck at this point because this selector box **does not show me the accounts (mailbox) that I have configured into Outlook**. It only shows "Outlook Data File" section, and my eg.: filippo.franchini@company.com is not displayed as an option.

This mailbox is configured to use IMAP protocol, but I don't think it is the cause of the issue. Does anyone know a possible reason for this behaviour of outlook export function?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your "Export to file" dialog, the one that shows the choices of "Comma Separate Values" and "Outlook Data File"... I've got Office 2016 and followed the steps and it appears in this order: 1) Select "Export to file" 2) Select file format (either CSV or PST) 3) Select mailbox. - E.g. https://youtu.be/WwYqBmBToLs?t=14

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've watched the video and the sequence of operation is exactly the same, and the procedure you followed is exactly the same that I have described, it seems we are all on the same boat : ) but I dont see my configured accounts at the last step

Comment: I have anyway uploaded the screenshot to show the steps : ) scroll bar is long in the last step but I assure that there is no other than the "Outlook data file", there is not my mailboxe account down there, and that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't export to CSV - try exporting to PST - This should then allow the email account in question to be exported to a PST file. CSV is only used for address books and calendars, which is why your account does not appear in the folder list.

Comment: Yes, choosing the .pst export allow me to view and select the desired mailbox account, but the issue here is that I need a list of email recipients in plain text format, that way I can subsequently process it with a script in order to obtain the desired result, can I obtain a plain text output?

Comment: Create the PST file, open the PST file in outlook, then follow the instructions here 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1449-outlook-extract-contacts.html#extract